# Differentiate object vs instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

Some consider model as an object, some consider as an instance. Can anyone tell me what is the difference between these two examples?

`model.py`:

```py
class ToDo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    due_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

`forms.py`:

```py
class ToDoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ToDo
        fields = ['name', 'due_date']
```

`views.py`:

```py
def todo_list(request):
    todos = ToDo.objects.all()
    context = {'todo_list': todos}
    return render(request, 'todoApp/todo_list.html', context)
```

Considering the code below, what is form instance?

```py
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CommentForm(self.request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            post = self.get_object()
            comment = form.instance
            comment.user = self.request.user
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('detail', slug=post.slug)

        return redirect('detail', slug=self.get_object().slug)
```

Comment: Which `object` you're refering to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in object-oriented programming, an object is an instance of a class. So model instance and model object are the same.

Let's do an example for that:

```py
# This is your class
class ToDo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    due_date = models.DateField()

# If somewhere I call
my_var = ToDo() # my_var contain an object or an instance of my model ToDo
```

As for your question about the form, each form in Django may or may not contain an instance. This instance is the object modified by the form. When you create an empty form, this `form.instance` is `None`, because your form is not bound to an object. But if you build a form taking an object to modify as its parameter or after filling it, this object is the instance.

Example:

```py
form = CommentForm()
print(form.instance) # This will return None, there is no instance bound to the form

comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=1)
form2 = CommentForm(instance=comment)
print(form2.instance) # Now the instance contain an object Comment or said an other way, an instance of Comment. When you display your form, the fields will be filled with the value of this instance
```

I hope that it's a little bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

`CommentForm` is `ModelForm` and `ModelForm` has `instance` attribute (which you can set (update scenario) or  `__init__` method of `CommentForm` will instantiate new model instance of model that you set to `Metaclass`

from [BaseModelForm](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L288) source:

```
if instance is None:
    # if we didn't get an instance, instantiate a new one
    self.instance = opts.model()
    object_data = {}
```